# Average from 2 different table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to average every hour data from 2 table (`cuaca` and `data_monitoring`) in MySQL then insert the result in another table (`average`) but my code doesn't work. If I just average from one table then insert the result in the another table, the code is working. I use scheduler because I need to know average result every hour

this ini my code, can you help me please?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE 
EVENT `otomatis` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR STARTS '2015-05-20 14:37:00' 
DO BEGIN
truncate table average;
INSERT INTO `average`
   (`tanggalave`, `avetemp`, `avehumid`,`avewind`) 
  SELECT `date` , avg(`suhu_udara`), avg(`kelembaban_udara`), avg(`kecepatan_angin`)
  FROM   `cuaca`
  GROUP By DATE( date ), HOUR( date );

INSERT INTO `average`
   (`avegel`) 
  SELECT  avg(`tinggi_gelombang`)
  FROM   `data_monitoring`
  GROUP By DATE( date ), HOUR( date );  

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Have you checked that the mysql event scheduler is on? @Tia

Comment: yes, the scheduler is on, when I try this code, it is only insert the result of average from `cuaca` table , not from `data_monitoring` table too :(

Comment: Do you need optimize query for this or not?

Comment: Maybe, but the most important I need to get average from different code because my coding doesn't work :( @pankaj

Comment: check fields of average table..if you have made not null as your query in the first line inserting for 4 fields but not for single field of second query..you may check sql error log too..

Comment: Is it possible if I want to insert together the result average from two table? @dev

Comment: if you are inserting two rows then it's not possible..IMHO to compare or anything the data try to insert the second table data with one field in an additional field of the first table..it will be a single insert query but will be using a variable to store the two tables record

Comment: not two row, I want in a one row there are the result average from two deifferent table, is it posible? 
Can you give the example about your answer? I don't understand